# The value of the local variable conn is not used

Tags: java, mysql, connection

As I mentioned on the subject, I am facing the warning "The value of the local variable conn is not used"

I clearly used the variable on my coding but it shows me that type of error.
It will be highly appreciated if you can advise me on this.

### [CODE]

```
package jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class example {
    public static void main(String[] ar) {


        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Success to find Driver");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("error = Failed to find driver");
        }//*Find MYSQL driver

        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/class", "root", "****");
            System.out.println("Connected to MySql");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("error = Failed to Create connection");
        }//* Creating Connection

        }
    }
```

---

[RESULT AFTER RUN]

Success to find Driver
error = Failed to Create connection

Comment: Well you define conn but you never do anything with it.  What do you expect should happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have assigned a reference to `conn` but you are not using that object anywhere, hence the *warning*.

To get rid of the warning either use it somewhere (maybe do a `sysout` somewhere) or add the `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` annotation

Comment: Thx for your reply. But 

Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/class", "root", "****");

I am using conn on here
Is this an wrong way to use this?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. Even if you use `Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/class", "root", "****");` you will get the same warning, because in either case you aren't using the object `conn` after assignment.

Comment: So appreciate for your prompt reply again.
As you can see the code, I am trying to make connection with correct credentials but it keep fail. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: There will be clues in the exception message.  Print the stacktrace.

Comment: Try : `System.err.println("error = Failed to Create connection" + e);` to get the exception.